# xampp-win32-7.0.9-0-VC14-installer not working windows 7

Tags: php, xampp

- I have installed [xampp-win32-7.0.9-0-VC14-installer](http://filehippo.com/download_xampp/)
- it shows error The procedure entry point ucrtbase.terminate could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
- After that I installed For Windows 64-bit http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x64.exe even after installation having same issue
- Error snapshot [image]

Comment: Is your Windows updated to the latest version?

Comment: Windows 7 ultimate SP1 64Bit Operating System

Comment: and you are installing its 32bit vsersion

Comment: I didn't asked for the OS, I asked if its latest updates are installed. If not please install them and then perform a clean install again.